# Sharepoint online: single web part css

Tags: css, online

Im trying to create nice titles for my webparts inside my SharePoint Online (Office 365). I got the following

Spanid = `WebPartCaptionWPQ5` and the css:
`.ms-webpart-titleText`

But how can i make only a webpart called News getting a blue background as example. Instead of all the webparts get a blue background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
<style type="text/css">
#WebPartWPQ5 .ms-webpart-titleText {
      background-color:blue;
}
</style>
```